# Is it a bad practice to call emit every 100 milliseconds in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a timer animation in my flutter that needs to update `currentRecordingDuration` by 1 every 100 milliseconds and I do it by calling emit inside of a timer:

```
timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (Timer t) {
  if (state.currentRecordingDuration >= state.maxRecordingDuration) {
    timer.cancel();
    return;
  }      
  emit(state.copyWith(
          currentRecordingDuration: state.currentRecordingDuration + 1));
});
```

This will cause the widget that implements the bloc to be updates every 100 milliseconds. I was wondering if this is a common occurrence in flutter, or if it's considered as bad practice.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a Ticker so that it's no faster than screen refresh?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz it's possible, but the code is more complex and I'm not sure if it's worth it, since the timer only runs for around 2 minutes.